# Programmatically referencing a javascript file at runtime

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem programatically referencing a javascript file from 
a javascript file. Normally I would just reference it in an html page but can't in this case as the directory location of the file is only available at runtime.  I have checked out several posts on this topic but as of yet have been unable to find anything that works. Below are code snippets from 4 files:

1. index.html assigns an ID to the header tag and references the first of two javascript files called scriptFile.js.
2. scriptFile.js, is a global data file for all new users.
3. A second file, also called scriptFile.js, is a user specific data file created for each user at runtime. The second javascript file contains data specific to a single user, is located in a different directory than  index.html scriptFile.js, but otherwise is structurally identical to the first scriptFile.js. In both cases the files consist of a function returning an array object.
4. The last file is index.js. Its purpose is to programmatically reference the second scriptFile.js file identified above.
5. When index.js runs, the value for scripts.length = 2 which is what it is supposed to be. scripts[0].getAttribute('id') and
   scripts[0].getAttribute('src') both output correctly. However, while scripts[1].getAttribute('id') outputs correctly as
   id = "scriptOneID", the scripts[1].getAttribute('src') outputs as null which is obviously incorrect. A second problem is
   that the data for the scriptOneID.enabled property outputs as true, when it should be outputing as false. This tells me
   that the object = loadData() statement is referencing data from the index.html scriptFile.js and not the
   index.js userNumber/scriptFile.js.  This has been verified in testing.

Here are the code snippets. Suggestions or ideas on how to correct this are appreciated. Thanks...

```
// 1. index.html page
<head id="headID">
<script id="scriptZeroID" type="text/javascript" src="scriptFile.js"> 
</script>  

// 2. scriptFile.js
function loadData()
{
  var object = [{ property: 0, enabled: true }];
  return object;
};

// 3. userNumber/scriptFile.js
function loadData()
{
  var object = [{ property: 0, enabled: false }];
  return object;
};

// 4. index.js page
//global declarations and assignments
var object = new Array;
object = loadData(); // assign the data in loadData function to an object array

// local declarations and assignments
var head = document.getElementById("headID");
var script = document.createElement("script");
var userNumber = sessionStorage.getItem("userNumber");
var scriptPath = userNumber + "/scriptFile.js";

script.id = "scriptOneID";
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.scr = scriptPath;
head.appendChild( script );

var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
console.log("script: " + scripts.length); // output = 2
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)
{
  console.log("output: " + scripts[i].getAttribute('id') + " / " + scripts[i].getAttribute('src'));
  // output for scripts[0]: id = "scriptZeroID", scr = "scriptFile.js"
  // output for scripts[1]: id = "scriptOneID", scr = null
};

object = loadData(); // assign the data in loadData function to an object array
console.log("print test value: " + object[1].enabled ); // output = true // this is incorrect, it should = false
```

Comment: Difficult to determine what issue is? Can you reproduce `html`, `javascript` at plnkr http://plnkr.co? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Typo: `script.scr`

Comment: Good catch on the typo but it won't fix his async problem.

Comment: Yes good catch. Thank you...

Comment: Just reran it.  That fixed the issue where scripts[1].getAttribute('src') outputs = null. Unfortunately as was indicated above, it does not correct the overall problem as scriptOneID.enabled property is still = true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is a script load time problem. In other words it's an asynchronous problem.

Javascript these days is fast. Really fast. Your script gets to your last call to "loadData" long before the script you injected into the head gets loaded. Therefore you are accessing the original version of "loadData" twice.

Just to clarify my comment on the "notification". Add a function like this (as an example) to you index.js file:

```
function populateObj() {
    object = loadData();
}
```

Then at the bottom of your injected script add:

```
populateObj();
```

That's all there is too it. When the injected script finishes loading and is executed your "object" global variable will have the correct data in it.

Comment: Would it help if I referenced the first script in the index.js file rather than the index.html file?

Comment: As @Korgrue suggested the jQuery method will help you know when the new version is "ready". However, the best way imho is to put a function in the injected script file that runs when it's loaded. This way you are "notified" when the async load is done and it never fails.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery has a function to load scripts at any time after page load.

Looks like this:

```
 $.getScript("yourscripttoload.js", function(){
    console.log("Script loaded and executed.");
  });
```

Maybe look into that to see if it will work in your situation.

Answer (score -1):

This is a complete poc solution on how to the programatically reference a javascript file from within a javascript file using a callback function that does not require jQuery. It is based on the premise that the same script file will be run during the page load and then again from a different location, with different data, during runtime . The following solution replaces index.js file in the above example.

```
// global declarations & assignments
var head = document.getElementById("headID");
var script = document.createElement("script");
var userNumber = sessionStorage.getItem("userNumber");
var scriptPath = userNumber + "/scriptFile.js";

// call back function
function loadScript(scriptPath, callback)
{
  script.id = "scriptOneID";
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = scriptPath;
  script.async = false;
  script.defer = false;
  // bind the load event to the callback function             
  script.onreadystatechange = callback;
  script.onload = callback;
  // append the script to the page header
  head.appendChild(script);
};

// place the code that you want to run inside an anonymous function
var anonymousFunction = function()
{
  var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
  console.log("script: " + scripts.length); // output = 2
  for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)
  {
    console.log("output: " + scripts[i].getAttribute('id') + " / " + 
    scripts[ i].getAttribute('src'));
    // output for scripts[0]: id = "scriptZeroID", scr = "scriptFile.js"
    // output for scripts[1]: id = "scriptOneID", scr = "1234567890/scriptFile.js" where userNumber = "1234567890"
  };

  object = loadData(); // assign the data in loadData function to an object array
  console.log("print test value: " + object[1].enabled ); // output =  false this is correct
};

// execute the loadScript function
loadScript( scriptPath, anonymousFunction );
```

Comment: Using `script.async = false` is deprecated and not recommended. Read the spec: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. It's going to cause you problems some day when they remove. Better off learning how to use asynchronous loading properly but hey you went out and did some actual research now, and then accepted your own answer.

Comment: One last comment. This article explains the problems with the "events" associated with loading script files http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html Read the part titled "Detecting Load Completion". I have also found the events to be quirky and unreliable on various platforms. Hence the answer (albeit simplified) that I gave you, which by the way contained no jQuery.

Comment: Sorry my answer is not acceptable to you.  It is a working (and tested) solution.  Yours was not! My intent was, and is, to provide information to other developers faced with similar programming challenges.  I thought that was the purpose here.  Cheers man...

Comment: I know my solution works. It's been tested many times. It's derived from that article I linked in my comment. The information you provided, is not exactly good information. Especially the `script.async = false` part. You can rail against what are the accepted solutions by those who do this a lot but it doesn't mean your answer is correct.

Comment: Look it man: 1. I appreciate the help you gave me. 2. I'm sorry if I hurt your feelings that was NOT my intent. 3. Rail all you want about the script.async property, but it is a good solution and it does work. 4. This is the end of my participation in this 'discussion'.